# Installing Mavericks on a new Mac Mini (end 2014) shipped with Yosemite pre-installed?

Tags: macos, mac-mini, downgrade

Excuse me for my english, I'm french and I try to find a solution for my new Mac Mini buy in December. My new Mac Mini it's configured with Yosemite 10.10.0. and it's a problem for me because I use some professional music software like Cubase Elements 7 or Studio One 2, it's not compatible for the moment with Yosmeite. I want to downgrade and I read your post and I'm in panic because I view that not possible to downgrade my new Mac Mini in OSX Mavericks. I have created a external bootable usb key with a Mavericks in my other Mac. When i restart on my usb key bootable, appear this symbol

[image]

It's the kernel panic when I try to boot on the usb key. I think it's mean it's not possible to downgrade on Mavericks with this New Mac Mini (end 2014) ?

Actually I'm in OSX 10.10.1, it's possible that the problem come because I'm in this version ?

Thanks for your help and your answers...

Comment: You would need to completely wipe the hard drive and start over.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is, you cannot instal an OS on a Mac that is older than the Mac itself.
See [Don't install a version of Mac OS X earlier than what came with your Mac](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201686)

That said, Cubase 7 should run OK on Yosemite, though you will need the [Steinberg Installer patch](http://www.steinberg.net/en/newsandevents/news/newsdetail/article/official-letter-on-yosemite-update-2837.html). I don't know Studio One 2 so I can't say on that.
Google did find this from [Presonus](http://support.presonus.com/entries/60005470-Studio-One-Crashing-with-Yosemite-Mac-OS-X-10-10) about it.

***Edit:*** I also found [this](http://support.presonus.com/entries/57764960-Mac-OSX-10-10-Yosemite-Compatibility-Statement-Updated-December-8th-), officially qualifying Studio One 2.6.4 as Yosemite-compatible

Answer (score -1):

When installing OS X, it automatically check if you qualify for the update with the apple servers (OS X 10.8 and above i think). That is why you can't downgrade OS X by installing older software. I do not know if there's a workaround for it, but I also can't imagine downgrading to OS X 10.9 Maverick from OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Comment: The reason is far simpler than that. The old OS doesn't have drivers for the new hardware.